# How do I calculate the following limit?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}$$
Using the fact that:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1.$$

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Start using the identity for the sine of the sum of two angles.

Comment: Simply expand $\sin (x+h)$ and you will find.

Comment: Depending on how you do it, you might also need $$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac {\cos(x) - 1}{x} = 0$$

Comment: Use $\sin(x+h)=\sin(x)\cos(h)+\sin(h)\cos(x)$ for starting.

Comment: http://www.coloringsun.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/A-Girl-with-an-Open-Book-Coloring-Page.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told in one of the comments use the following identity:-$$\sin(x+h)=\sin(x)\cos(h)+\sin(h)\cos(x)$$ Now plugging this in you get$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)\cos(h)+\sin(h)\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{h}$$ this becomes $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)[\cos(h)-1]+{\sin(h)\cos(x)}}{h}$$ now dividing the h between the two numerator expression this becomes $$\lim_{h\to 0}[{\frac{{\sin(x)[\cos(h)-1]}}{h}+\frac{{\sin(h)\cos(x)}}{h}}]$$ here as the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{{\cos(h)-1}}{h}}$ goes to zero, we're left with $$\cos(x)\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(h)}{h}$$ and using the idea you mentioned this becomes $\cos(x)$

Comment: where you say "this becomes", I think you want to say $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)[\cos(\color{red}h)-1]+{\sin(h)\cos(x)}}{h}$

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Use [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formula,

$$\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)=2\sin\dfrac{x+h-x}2\cos\dfrac{x+h+x}2$$